# Entity Framework: Only Seed when building initial database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using *Entity Framework 6* with this `DbMigrationsConfiguration`:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Danfoss.EnergyEfficiency.Data.DataContext context)
    {
        //Adding initial data to context

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

I'm using it in *WebAPI* in this way:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Configuration>());
}
```

I have noticed that `Seed` function is running every time my application start up. How can I prevent this? I only like it to run the first time it runs, when it build the initial tables.

Comment: In my projects I use [`AddOrUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) instead. Something like `context.Table.AddOrUpdate(entity => entity.Id, new Entity{ Id = 1 });`. Would that work?

Comment: I'm doing that aswell. But my Seed method has a lot of data to handle including some CSV import. I don't like that to happen every time I start my application.

Comment: You can have a settings table with a bit value saying whether the database has been seeded or not and then act by that value when the seed method is started, e.g. returning right away when you found out that the seed has been already used.

Answer (score 4):

The `DbMigrationsConfiguration.Seed` method is called every time you call `Update-Database`. The reasoning behind that is explained in this blog by [One Unicorn](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/).

That means that you have to write your `Seed` code to cope with existing data. If you don't like that, you can vote for a change on [CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/843).

In the meantime, to quote the blog:

> The best way to handle this is usually to not use AddOrUpdate for
>   every entity, but to instead be more intentional about checking the
>   database for existing data using any mechanisms that are appropriate.
>   For example, Seed might check whether or not one representative entity
>   exists and then branch on that result to either update everything or
>   insert everything

Another option, that I have used in the past, is to add standing data that is related to a migration in the migration itself, using the `Sql` command. That way it only runs once. I have tended to move away from this because I prefer to keep the seeding in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in that I wanted an initial user created on database build. What I did was to create a blank migration and then add in the user creation there. Since a migration technically runs only once unless you remove and reapply migrations, this would ensure it would only run once on database creation. 
I know that this question is a bit old, so it may help others or you may not be using migrations. But if you are, this is a handy technique.